# Kendo UI Grid & Web API - HTTP 500 error on POST

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I keep getting a HTTP 500 error when I try to create new records. The ID field for each record is a string and not an integer by the way. I used Chrome to analyze the issue. When I tried to add new records, the ID field is not sent in form data.

Comment: what does the response message body say?

Comment: I've edited my question to show the response.

Comment: Well.. what's in ´EntityValidationErrors´ and how do you set up the grid?

Comment: 'EntityValidationErrors' isn't in my model. I assume it's part of EntityFramework. Let me update the question to show the grid initialization.

Comment: The reason for EntityValidationErrors could be that you don't send the Id, so EF is trying to add new entity without Id, this is probably the exception. So catch some exceptions and try to analyse the 'EntityValidationErrors' to see which field causes the issue. Also note that it's better practice to create ViewModels to separate your entity classes from the Views.

Comment: It is correct that no I'd is being passed, because it is a new record so the id is undefined. It looks like one of the fields has invalid data. What does your model look like in c#?

Comment: Show us the definition of your `Industry` class in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Initially I thought the ID was the issue but seems like it only applies to update & delete events, which work fine by the way. I've edited my question to include the Industry class and ViewModel.

Comment: This is what I got from catching exceptions - Entity of type "Industry" in state "Added" has the following validation errors:
- Property: "IndustryId", Error: "The IndustryId field is required."

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I didn't have to use IndustryId as a string after all. Changed it to an integer and now it works fine.

I was using the Industry entity as a foreign key in another grid. Since the MultiSelect widget was also in use, I was under the impression that IndustryId had to be in string format in order to be displayed as an array in the grid.

### Update

Changing IndustryId to an integer did help, but I still have issues when updating and creating a new Industry item. Not sure why this is happening. I will have a look at my code again just to make sure I haven't overlooked any important steps.